# Who gets the 2 bonus victory points for reaching a new island?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

When expanding to an island, would the first person on the new island get 2 bonus victory points?  Or does everybody get 2 bonus points if it is their first expansion on that island?  If the same players gets to 2 different islands first, do they get 2 bonus points for each settlement?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! If you haven't already, please check out [the tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour). I've edited your question to make it clearer; if you don't like it, feel free to edit it further. We hope you stick around and ask many more great questions like this one!

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, no points are granted for expanding to an island.

That said, some of the scenarios have a special rule that grant points for expanding to an island. For example, scenarios 1, 4, 8 and 9 have the following special rule:

> If you build a settlement on a foreign island, you receive a
>   Special Victory Point! Take a Catan chit and place it under the
>   settlement when you build it. Each player may earn only ONE
>   Special Victory Point in this scenario. It does not matter if
>   other players have already built settlements on that island.

In those scenarios, every player that builds on an island other than the one on which they started gets 1 bonus point, but only the first time they do so.